# search a sentence in a directory with 100 Excel-Files (xlsx)

Tags: windows-7

i have in one directory 100 Excel-Files (*.xlsx)

i'm looking for one Sentence "WW-XX"

How can i find out in which Excel-File  is these "WW-XX"?

Comment: I already use Windows 10, but as far as I remember already in windows 7 search works for office files' content too

Answer (score 1):

If you wish Windows Search to search Excel files, you need to set it up.

- Run *Control Panel > Indexing Options*
- Click *Advanced*
- Find and click `xlsx`
- Tick *Index Properties and File Contents*
- Click *OK*

[image]

Comment: wie komme ich zum Control Panel

Comment: wie zu Indexing Options ?

Comment: wie zu Click Advanced ?

Comment: Don't know German, so just guessing (google translate) : *Systemsteuerung > Indizierungsoptionen > Erweitert*